# How to use 'io.StringIO' with 'print >>'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stringio

I got the following error:

```
 Second line.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print >>output, u'Second line.'
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

When I run the following code. I don't know what is wrong. Could anybody show me how to fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import io
output = io.StringIO()
output.write(u'First line.\n')
print u'Second line.'
print >>output, u'Second line.'
contents = output.getvalue()
print contents
output.close()
```

Answer (score 13):

For Python 2 consider using the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stringio.html) module instead of io.

#### Code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
```

#### Test Code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
output = StringIO()
output.write(u'First line.\n')
print u'Second line.'
print >>output, u'Second line.'
contents = output.getvalue()
print contents
output.close()
```

#### Results:

```
Second line.
First line.
Second line.
```

Comment: You meant `print contents.encode('utf-8')` since contents is of the type `unicode`? Also, `io.StringIO` is available in python2, when it instead of `StringIO.StringIO` should be used?

Comment: io is available but it is a back port from Python 3.  Evidently print redirection confuses it.  You are using Python2 only features, so the StringIO module could be fine to use.

Comment: if you want to use the backported `io.StringIO` you should also be using the backported `print` with `from __future__ import print_function`